# WinApi : Add style to combo box

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to add CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED style to an existing combobox , my code doesn't work and I have no idea why . 
I suspect maybe the expression oldStyle | addedStyle is not valid , but I can't figure out why.

```
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(
    L"ComboBox",
    L"",
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST ,
    200,
    200,
    200,
    200,
    parentHandle,
    (HMENU)1,
    GetModuleHandle(NULL),
    NULL);

auto comboBoxStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
comboBoxStyle = comboBoxStyle | CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED;
SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, comboBoxStyle);
```

the output is just regular combobox , without any change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular style can only be specified at creation time. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775796.aspx#CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED) alludes to this when it says:

> **CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED**
>
> Specifies that the owner of the list box is responsible for drawing its contents and that the items in the list box are all the same height. The owner window receives a WM_MEASUREITEM message when the combo box is created and a WM_DRAWITEM message when a visual aspect of the combo box has changed.